# Fill in the blank: A "general term" vs an "umbrella term". How to choose?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

> Chronic pain is ________ term for any type of persistent pain, from migraines to fibromyalgia, that lasts anywhere from several months to the whole of life.
>
> Option 1: *a general*
>   Option 2: *an umbrella*

I am told that the answer is option 2. Why not option 1?

My dictionary says:
An *umbrella term* is a word or phrase that covers a broad interval or set of functions or items that all fall under a single common category.
From my understanding a *general term* means a common term. E.g. Engineering is a general term for computer engineering, mechanical engineering etc.

I intuitively understand 'an umbrella' is a better option but I am not able to justify it logically.

Comment: What research have you done here? Have you looked up the words in a dictionary?

Comment: You may well still have difficulty finding a satisfactory answer, but the attempt should be made and the results accompany your question on ELU.

Comment: @WS2 I have googled it, asked others and thought a lot about it myself. I am not able to justify the answer.

Comment: Show your findings (a few examples containing 'general term' and 'umbrella term'?). (2) is certainly not wrong.

Comment: In casual conversation, both convey a similar idea, as does *generic*.

Comment: Who told you that only one of those is correct, and what was the reason they gave? Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: I think this is just a bad example.  Both words are commonly used.  It isn't obvious to me why "general" would be incorrect.